# HttpPost from android to ASP.Net Page

Tags: android, asp.net, http-post

How can I post a request using HttpPost from android to Asp.Net page?

I use such that

```
HttpPost request =  new HttpPost(m_WebRequestUrl);
            HttpParams params =  new BasicHttpParams();
            params.setParameter("Test", "Test");
            request.setParams(params);
            client.setParams(params);
            response = client.execute(request);
```

Regards
Shibu

Answer (score 1):

Whether Asp.Net or Php etc. doesnt matter .On server side you have to have a service that handles your request and responses in appropriate way.
Your request is good to go.